# how to get the value after executing the background worker in the nunit test case?

Tags: c#, winforms, nunit-3.0

I have a method which performs the operation on the background worker. now i need to add the test case for the same method.

How can i get the actual value which is applied after running the background worker?

```
    public class CustomControl
    {
        public int values = 0;
        public void OKButtonClick()
        {

            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
            {
                CreateFilterPredicates();
            };
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                values = 10;
            };
            if (!worker.IsBusy)
            {
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }


   [Test]        
    public void OKClickTest()
    {
        CustomControl filter = new CustomControl();
        filter.OKButtonClick();

        //How to get the value is passed?
        if (filter.values == 10)
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }
        else Assert.Fail();
    }
```

Comment: I sometimes put `while loop` to wait for value to appear, before asserting it. And just to protect myself from test never stop running I mark it with `TimeoutAttribute`

Comment: How can i check whether the value is appeared or not ?

Comment: Are you serious or joking? Declare `private volatile bool _isCompleted` and set it to true in `RunWorkerCompleted` --> `while (!_isCompleted)`

Comment: I have tried this, but it not works for me. The 'RunWorkerCompleted` is not invoked after complteing the task in the DoWork. Is there I have done any thing wrong?

Comment: You need to enable `CanRaiseEvents`